# How to access multiple elements generated from ngFor directive in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to add CSS class to div elements generated with *ngFor Angular directive. Firstly, I tried with @ViewChild directive and Renderer2, but it seems it does not work with multiple elements. Secondly, I tried to manipulate div elements with @ViewChildren directive, but could not find a suitable syntax example that would work for me. How can I access those elements and work with their classList?

The error message that I get is: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: el.classList is undefined addClass`

HTML

```html
 <div
    class="row" #rowDiv
    *ngFor="let courtReservation of currentIntervalReservations"
 >
      <div class="court">
        <h1 class="court-name">{{ courtReservation.courtName }}</h1>
      </div>
      <lp-player-diagram
        *ngFor="let res of courtReservation.reservations; let i = index"
        [playerName]="res.playerName"
        [index]="i"
      ></lp-player-diagram>
 </div>
```

TS

```js
export class MainGantogramComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {   
   @ViewChildren('rowDiv') rowElements?: QueryList<HTMLDivElement>;

   constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

   /* ... */

   setGridTemplateClass(currentTime: Time) {
      if (currentTime.minutes == 0) {
        this.rowElements?.forEach((div) =>
          this.renderer.addClass(div, 'short-grid-template')
        );
      } else {
        this.rowElements?.forEach((div) =>
          this.renderer.addClass(div, 'standard-grid-template')
        );
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can just use a field to store the css class you need:

```
 <div
    class="row"
    [ngClass]="gridClass"
    *ngFor="let courtReservation of currentIntervalReservations"
 >
      <div class="court">
        <h1 class="court-name">{{ courtReservation.courtName }}</h1>
      </div>
      <lp-player-diagram
        *ngFor="let res of courtReservation.reservations; let i = index"
        [playerName]="res.playerName"
        [index]="i"
      ></lp-player-diagram>
 </div>

----

setGridTemplateClass(currentTime: Time) {
  this.gridClass = currentTime.minutes === 0 ? 'short-grid-template' : 'standard-grid-template'
}
```

this is how it works in angular, `Renderer` is very seldom used